# how to eliminate null value from the nsarray?

Tags: iphone, nsarray

I am having one array where i am fetching data from database for some specific value,and hence the key where that particular value is not there,it is fetching null value in the array.

Now,my question is how can i eliminate that null value from the array? I tried to fetch the nsarray value to nsstring and then to another array,but then it is not fetching the whole array,but takes the last indexed value.

Please help me out. Thank you.

I am attaching code for further reference :

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"webservice from where i m fetching data"];
NSLog(url);
NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];

NSData *returnData = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse: nil error: nil ];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
dataArray=[[returnString JSONValue] retain];
[self setAlldetails:dataArray];     

nsarray *InteName = [alldetails valueForKey:@"IntelligenceName"];
```

So the array fetches value for array InteName like this :

```
(
    "00:00:00",
    "00:00:00",
    "17:15:00",
    "17:15:00",
    "17:15:00",
    "17:15:00",
    "00:00:00",
    "00:00:00",
    "17:15:00",
    "17:15:00",
    "17:15:00",
    "17:15:00",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>"
)
```

so now,i want to remove occurance of the value null.

any guesses??

Comment: Give some code to track your mistake in your code.

Comment: filteredArrayUsingPredicate:. Way less code than the below solutions.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't be surprised if it has a better runtime than O(n).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got the solution while doing T & E :

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
array = [InteName retain];
NSLog(@"Array : : %@",array);

NSMutableArray *array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSString *str;
for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
{
    str = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    if(str !=[NSNull null])
    {
        [array1 addObject:str]; 
        //[array removeObjectAtIndex:i];
    }
}
```

Comment: One suggestion: if(![str isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) rather than if(str !=[NSNull null]).  The latter posts a warning.

Comment: @mpemburn the identity check is sufficient and much faster also. Cast either of the two to `id` and the warning should go away.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I am reading your question correctly, but assuming you want to get rid of the null entries in your array and that they are actually `@"<null>"` strings:

```
NSMutableArray *array = ...;
for (id nullObject in array)
{
   if ([nullObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class] && [nullObject isEqualToString:@"<null>"]
   {
      [array removeObjectAtIndex:i];
   }
}
```

Comment: This will throw, as you are changing the array while iterating over it.

Comment: This code is also throwing exception with the same error message shown above,as null is compared to null value.What should i do to eliminate the things??

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *nulls = [NSMutableArray array];
for (id candidate in dataArray)
    if (candidate == [NSNull null])
        [nulls addObject:candidate];
[dataArray removeObjectsInArray:nulls]; // assuming dataArray is mutable
```

Comment: hey Zoul,Thanks for the help. i tried your code,but it is terminated with following : -[NSNull isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x264ad68
2010-11-26 15:05:50.104 [4275:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x264ad68'
.....terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”. This is because,it will compare null with null.